# What is stored in pg_default tablespace?

Tags: postgresql

I have ~2.5 TB database, which is divided into tablespaces. The problem is that ~250 GB are stored in pg_defalut tablespace.

I have 3 tables and 6 tablespaces: 1 per each table and 1 for its index. Each tablespace directory is not empty, so there are no missing tablespaces for some tables/indexes. But the size of data/main/base/OID_of_database directory is about 250 GB.

Can anyone tell me what is stored there, is it OK, and if not, how can I move it to tablespace?

I am using PostgreSQL 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspect the `base` subdirectory of the data directory. It will contain number directories that correspond to your databases and perhaps a `pgsql_tmp` directory.

Find out which directory contains the 250GB. Map directory names to databases using

```
SELECT oid, datname
FROM pg_database;
```

Once you have identified the directory, change into it and see what it contains.

Map the numbers to database objects using

```
SELECT relname, relkind, relfilenode
FROM pg_class;
```

(Make sure you are connected to the correct database.)

Now you know which objects take up the space.

If you had frequent crashes during operations like `ALTER TABLE` or `VACUUM (FULL)`, the files may be leftovers from that. They can theoretically be deleted, but I wouldn't do that without consulting with a PostgreSQL expert.